# how to change color of table view title

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Can we change the color of the table view title the string which i am showing appears in gray color can we choose color for it .Is there any property of table view title
 i am not asking for table view header or footer i mean the title

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 // Keep space in the following line ........ DONT REMOVE
 return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select your service:"];
}
```

Comment: i got this 
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section       
{
 tempHeader = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Dear "];
 tempHeader = [tempHeader stringByAppendingString:appDelegate.KFirstname];
 tempHeader = [tempHeader stringByAppendingString:@"                                     Select your service:"];
 
 
    UILabel *v= [[UILabel alloc] init];

 v.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
 v.text=tempHeader;
   // [v.textColor.CGColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    return v;
}

but i want it to look same as it looks just red color should appear to string

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom header view, by implementing the [`-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:).

There's no documented way to change the title color. (The undocumented way is override `-[UITableHeaderFooterView setText:]`.)